# How to do hit testing inside a closed shape composed only of lines (no fill)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, system.drawing

How to do it? The figure is an instance of DrawingVisual and DrawingContext.DrawLine is used to draw closed shapes.

As a makeshift solution, i draw a semi transparent line, almost invisible, of the thickness equal to that of the entire shape. This way it responds to hit testing. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I was going to recommend using an enclosing border and use hit testing over that. But you have kind of implemented the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comment is the right answer:

> I was going to recommend using an enclosing border and use hit testing
>   over that. But you have kind of implemented the same thing. ([AngelWPF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/164184/angelwpf))

Answer (score 0):

If your shape is convex, then for each segment (A ; B) of you shape you must do the following :

- build the 3d vector vector MA (M is the click position and A the first point of the current segment).
- build the 3d vector BA (B is the second point of the current segment and A the first point of the current segment)
- calculate the dot product MA + BA, if the direction of the resulting vector are always the same for all the segments your point is in the shape.

If your shape is not convex you must split it into convex shape first then apply the previous method on each convex shape.

Comment: This is a solution requiring to calculate things using code, i was looking for something that is built in into WPF, like hit test feture for shapes such as rectangle (DrawRectangle method). Also i am working in a totally 2D environment.